# Jquery animation one ends then start second

Tags: jquery, html

I create two arrow and respectively two counters. Arrow one animate up with counter one (first child) counts when ends, arrow two and counter two (child 2) start. I tried as below but not works. I don't understood what's the wrong ?Please help me to solve this problem. Please see css code for animation class.

```js
    $('.mid-section-container').each(function(i) {
     $('.arrow-one img').css({'opacity':'0'}).delay(1000*i).addClass('animate-arrow'),{}
     $('.mid-section-top-row-right-container:first-child').fadeOut(0);
     $('.arrow-two img').css({'opacity':'0'}).delay(8000*i).addClass('animate-arrow');
     $('.mid-section-top-row-right-container:nth-child(2)').fadeOut(0);
     setTimeout(function() {
      $('.arrow-one img').css({'opacity':'1'});
      $('.mid-section-top-row-right-container:first-child').delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1000);
     },1000, function() {
      $('.arrow-two img').css({'opacity':'1'});
      $('.mid-section-top-row-right-container:nth-child(2)').delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1000);
     }, 1000);
    });
    
    $('.count').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
      
      $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
        countNum: countTo
      },
    
      {
    
        duration: 8000,
        easing:'linear',
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
          $this.text(this.countNum);
          //alert('finished');
        }
    
      });  
    });
```

```css
    .mid-section-container {
     background: url(../images/mid-setion-bg.png);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: contain;
    }
    .mid-section-top-row {
     display: flex;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 15px;
    // border: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    .mid-section-top-row-left,
    .mid-section-top-row-right {
     display: flex;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     width: 50%;
     height: 350px;
    // border: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    .arrow-one,
    .arrow-two{
     height: 131px;
     margin: 0 10px;
    }
    .arrow-one img,
    .arrow-two img{
     width: auto;
     height: 100%;
    }
    .arrow-one {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #353FF2; /*--blue--*/
    }
    .arrow-two {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #D9CC1E; /*--yellow green--*/
    }
    
    .mid-section-top-row-right {
     display: black;
     flex-direction: column;
    }
    .mid-section-top-row-right-container {
     display: flex;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #A53692; /*blue purple*/
    }
    .animate-arrow {
     animation: animate 9s ease;
     animation-delay: 0.4s;
     transform-origin: 0 100%;
    }
    @keyframes animate {
     0% {transform: scaleY(0);
     }
     100% {transform: scaleY(100%);
     }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animate {
     0% {transform: scaleY(0);
     }
     100% {transform: scaleY(100%);
     }
    }
    .left {
     width: 104px;
     margin: 0 10px;
     font-size: 48px;
     font-weight: 700;
    }
    .right {
     margin-left: 20px;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: 500;
     line-height: 20px;
    }
    .mid-section-top-row-right-container:first-child {
     color: #353FF2; /*--blue--*/
    }
    .mid-section-top-row-right-container:nth-child(2) {
     color: #D9CC1E; /*--yellow green--*/
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML

    <div class="mid-section-container">
     <div class="mid-section-top-row">
      <div class="mid-section-top-row-left">
       <div class="arrow-one"><img src="images/arrow_blue.png" alt="arrow-blue" /></div>
       <div class="arrow-two"><img src="images/arrow_yellow.png" alt="arrow-yellow" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mid-section-top-row-right">
       <div class="mid-section-top-row-right-container">
        <div class="left"><span class="counter-one count" data-count="1.6">0</span>M</div>
        <div class="right">Some text here</div>
       </div>
       <div class="mid-section-top-row-right-container">
        <div class="left"><span class="counter-two count" data-count="800">0</span>+</div>
        <div class="right">Some text here</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--mid-section-top-row-->
```

Comment: add you css here and all the script, for annimation

Comment: @Springer, Please check updates.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setTimeout function in Jquery section is wrong it must follow this structure

> setTimeout(callback, time)

To fix this you can change like follow

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.arrow-one img').css({
    'opacity': '1'
  });
  $('.mid-section-top-row-right-container:first-child').delay(1000 * i).fadeIn(1000);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('.arrow-two img').css({
    'opacity': '1'
  });
  $('.mid-section-top-row-right-container:nth-child(2)').delay(1000 * i).fadeIn(1000);
}, 1000);
```

Please refer to the [setTimeout function in here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for more detail.

Comment: Sorry, This I did and works mean both arrow animate same time but I want when one arrow animation finishes then second arrow animation start

Comment: You can set first arrow animation run in 2000 second and then delay the second arrow 2000 second. So after the first arrow finishes then the second arrow starts.

Comment: I tried this also, what happens, when 1st arrow animation start after sometime second arrow animation start before 1st arrow animation end. So I increase set time value equal to animation time value after this when 1st arrow animation ends, second arrow animation also ends in background and second arrow image and counter value is shown without animation.